# Defining Dynamic Array

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

How can I define a dynamic array in C#?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

C# doesn't provide dynamic arrays. Instead, it offers List class which works the same way.

To use lists, write at the top of your file:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
```

And where you want to make use of a list,  write (example for strings):

```
List<string> mylist = new List<string>();
mylist.Add("First string in list");
```

Comment: This isn't really an array per se, but rather a collection. Although it can be accessed like an array, in memory it's stored as a linked list.

Comment: I don't think a List is internally stored as a linked list. It has to be as an array.

Comment: No, a List is a linked list internally. What makes you think it must be an array?

Comment: `List<T>` is using an array internally. You can find this either with Reflector or in the documentation.

Comment: Anon: The defined performance characteristics for example. Each List method such as Add state their time complexity.

Comment: Generic List uses an array internally, not a linked list. @Anon: What makes you think it's a linked list? Use reflector and check it for yourself.

Comment: List<T> is not a linked list. LinkedList<T> is a linked list.

Answer (score 8):

Take a look at [Array.Resize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ffy6686(VS.85).aspx) if you need to resize an array.

```
    // Create and initialize a new string array.
    String[] myArr = {"The", "quick", "brown", "fox", "jumps", 
        "over", "the", "lazy", "dog"};

    // Resize the array to a bigger size (five elements larger).
    Array.Resize(ref myArr, myArr.Length + 5);

    // Resize the array to a smaller size (four elements).
    Array.Resize(ref myArr, 4);
```

Alternatively you could use the List class as others have mentioned.  Make sure you specify an [initial size](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dw8e0z9z.aspx) if you know it ahead of time to keep the list from having to resize itself underneath.  See the remarks section of the initial size link.

```
    List<string> dinosaurs = new List<string>(4);

    Console.WriteLine("\nCapacity: {0}", dinosaurs.Capacity);

    dinosaurs.Add("Tyrannosaurus");
    dinosaurs.Add("Amargasaurus");
    dinosaurs.Add("Mamenchisaurus");
    dinosaurs.Add("Deinonychus");
```

If you need the array from the List, you can use the [ToArray()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x303t819.aspx) function on the list.

```
    string[] dinos = dinosaurs.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

C# does provide dynamic arrays and dynamic array manipulation.  The base of an array is dynamic and can be modified with a variable.  You can find the array tutorial here (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).  I have also included code that demonstrates an empty set array and a dynamic array that can be resized at run time.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int x = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        int y = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine(x);
        {


            int[] dynamicArray1 = { };//empty array
            int[] numbers;//another way to declare a variable array as all arrays start as variable size
            numbers = new int[x];//setting this array to an unknown variable (will be user input)

            for (int tmpInt = 0; tmpInt < x; tmpInt++)//build up the first variable array (numbers)
            {
                numbers[tmpInt] = tmpInt;
            }
            Array.Resize(ref numbers,y);// resize to variable input
            dynamicArray1 = numbers;//set the empty set array to the numbers array size 
            for (int z = 0; z < y; z++)//print to the new resize
            {
                Console.WriteLine(numbers[z].ToString());//print the numbers value
                Console.WriteLine(dynamicArray1[z].ToString());//print the empty set value
            }
        }
        Console.Write("Dynamic Arrays  ");
        var name = Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can have Dynamic Arrays in C# it's very simple.
keep in mind that the response to your question above is also correct you could declare a 
List Generic
The way to Create a Dynamic Array would be to declare your Array for example

```
        string[] dynamicArry1 = { };//notice I did not declare a size for the array
        List<String> tmpList = new List<string>();
        int i = 1;
        for(int tmpInt = 0; tmpInt < 5; tmpInt++)
        {
           tmpList.Add("Testing, 1.0." + tmpInt + ", 200, 3.4" + tmpInt +"," + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString());
           //dynamicArry1[tmpInt] = new string[] { tmpList[tmpInt].ToCharArray() };
        }
        dynamicArry1 = tmpList.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

how about ArrayList ?

If I'm not wrong ArrayList is an implementation of dynamic arrays

Answer (score 0):

Example of Defining Dynamic Array in C#:

```
        Console.WriteLine("Define Array Size? ");
        int number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Enter numbers:\n");
        int[] arr = new int[number];

        for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
        {
            arr[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++ )
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Array Index: "+i + " AND Array Item: " + arr[i].ToString());
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score -1):

like so

```
int nSize = 17;
int[] arrn = new int[nSize];

nSize++;
arrn = new int[nSize];
```