# How to set variable type on runtime or use generics in member variable?

Tags: c#, arrays, generics

I am reading data from a file, where I am expecting a sequence of data (Array of data).

The data can be of different types...

```
Array<double>
Array<double[]>
Array<double[,]>
Array<double[,,]>
Array<double[,,,]>
Array<double[,,,,]>
Array<double[,,,,,]>
Array<double[,,,,,,]>
Array<double[,,,,....n]>
```

Right now, I have used cases for each case and wrote code for maximum 10 dimensions. But I want it to be for `n-dimensions`.

Is there any other way to write/read data to array without writing nested loops?

Details: (EDIT)
I am reading a binary file, in which two things are specified before the data, 
1) Dimensions list
2) Element-Limit

I read these list of integers and build my data type. 
For example:

Dimensions = `{15,32,128,5}` 
Element-Limit = `{15,32,128,5}`

Then I build a 4D- array like this

```
double[,,,] dataStream = new double[15,32,128,5];
```

And this dimension and element-limit may be of `n-numbers`

And one thing more, I am reading a collection of data... this `dataStream` will go in `Array` then like this `Array<double[,,,]>`

Comment: Please show us your code.

Comment: How is your file structured? and How you are planning to interpret the contents? Please give some detailed information.

Comment: Why don't you use: `Array<object>` ?

Comment: What exactly you want to achieve after reading the data? Probably you are looking for dynamic declaration of arrays then see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1933102/3266029) as well as you can use variable to declare the array.

Comment: @UsmanAzam, why didn't you use List instead of Arrays?

Comment: @WaqasShabbir using `List` against an `double[,,,]` means `List<List<List<List<double>>>>`